Rational Function Equation from a Graph

Question: Find the equation to the rational function.
Answer:
Step 1: Satisfy vertical asymptotes and zeros.
$y=k\dfrac{(x+2)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x-2)}$
Step 2: Satisfy the point $(0,2)$:
$2=k\dfrac{(0+2)(0-3)}{(0+1)(0-2)}$.
Gives $k=2/3$.
Step 3 and my question. How to satisfy the Horizontal Asymptote?

You indeed need one more degree of freedom, i.e. another parameter to play with.
One way to achieve that is adding a parameter $m$ and adding a factor
$$\frac{mx^2\pm 1}{x^2+1}$$
to your expression, which has no zeros nor poles and whose limit is $m$ as $x\to\infty$, where the $\pm 1$ depends on the sign of $m$.
In you case the factor whould be
$$\frac{\frac{3}{2}x^2+ 1}{x^2+1}$$
